# How to construct a CSS selector for the input element as per the HTML

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I am new to selenium IDE and am trying to find an input element that is within two div elements. I am unsure of the CSS selector syntax to do so. The only requirement is that I would like to use the id of the input element as that is consistent across the sites I am trying to automate. Attached is the HTML.

P.S. I am using eclipse and Java

[image: HTML snippet]

Comment: Why not use the `id` of the input as a selector?

Comment: What does your code look like? As @StaticBeagle says, what about `driver.findElement(By.id("show_hidden"));`?

Comment: In css you select element using ID # sign followed by id like in Your example for input is #show_hidden{border:1px solid red;} .

Comment: @ggorlen That is exactly what I tried first and I get an ElementNotFound error, so my assumption was that I had to focus the selector on the parent div first.

Comment: That seems strange. Are you sure the DOM is loaded properly? Can you dump the DOM in Java rather than looking at the Chrome dev tools?

Comment: Just a quick note on one of your comments -- you **don't** have to focus on the parent element in order to search by `id`. `document.getElementById("show_hidden")` will always find an `<input id="show_hidden">`, regardless of where you're searching.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Must be something else causing the error then, since I do a simple getElementById on that input name and it still appears

Answer (score 1):

You can use any of these

```
   .sortable-list .btn-3 input{
      height: 40px;
      border: 1px solid red;
    }
```

or

```
   div div input{
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the *HTML* you have shared, to invoke `click()` on the `<input>` tag you can use the following *cssSelector*:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.sortable_list#upd_list div#widget_tools label[for=show_hidden]")).click();
```

As an alternative you can also use the following `xpath`:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='sortable_list' and @id='upd_list']//div[@id='widget_tools']//label[@for='show_hidden']")).click();
```